# Node.js: What's the difference between NowJS and Pusher?

Tags: node.js

What are the differences between NowJS and Pusher?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NowJS is currently Node.js-only, even though you can use it with other platforms like Rails with simple requests between the two server stacks.
Pusher can be used on a variety of platforms.

NowJS is free, while Pusher is not.

Pusher is a cloud service, where they host the servers for you. NowJS, and their enterprise offering NowCluster, is not a cloud service, allowing you to host and manage servers on private & public clouds like AWS. The advantage of a cloud service is that it requires no managing of servers. The disadvantage of a cloud service is that it is a single point-of-failure residing with a 3rd party. The former makes the lives of individual developers easier, while the latter fits with the needs of enterprises.

To make the lives of individual developers and startups easier, NowJS may soon be available on various platforms as a service like Heroku and CloudFoundry and others. NowJS can already be easily deployed some of the Node.js Platform-as-a-Service providers such as Nodester, providing the ease-of-use benefits of a PaaS.

Comment: For small sites pusher is free to use.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but Pusher is free for 20 concurrent users/connections. On the other hand, NowJS is free for 10,000 concurrent users/connections.

Comment: Pusher is free when max 20 connections simultaneous and 100,000 messages(the number of messages part is also important) per day. NowJS does not have a message limit per day and I also have not benchmarked NowJS to tell you it can handle 10,000 concurrent users per box, but yeah I think you are right about that.

Comment: small sites probably won't have more than that limit.

Answer (score 5):

As an addendum, here's RMSN - a drop in replacement for Pusher that I've written using NowJS.
https://github.com/leppert/RMSN

Answer (score 1):

There are naturally lots of differences, but mainly:

Pusher is a framework that can be used with several platforms (Java, Python, PHP, Ruby, and lots more) and uses a centralized server at pusher.com with your account that handles the Comet-technology stack.

NowJS is all node and runs on your own server.

Comment: Well, yes, but in a very different way. :-P